# 28,000 rows being returned very slowly in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have what is a very simple get that literally grabs the entire DB set and returns it over the wire. The set in question is around 28k rows at the moment.

When testing locally, the calls to the database are completed in less than a second, but the swagger call takes around a minute. In our production environment it takes about 1-2 minutes to complete the call (we don't have timing code there for exact db calls, but we are timing on the front-end how long it takes, and it is also 1-2 minutes).

Something between the data call and it arriving to the front-end is taking a long time, and I'm not sure exactly how to resolve it.

The code is literally:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllCustomers()
{
    return Ok(_context.Customers);
}
```

What else can I do to debug this?

Our working solution is going to be to restrict the dataset down significantly, returning < 1000 records instead, but the business preference is to have everything and let a front-end table sort and filter it.

On a lark, I removed all the related objects from the model, and stripped it down to the 10 or so columns in the table, and it still took a very long time.

Comment: Any lazy loading involved? In other words, does your entity have related data and if yes, are you using (enabled) the lazy loading? I would suggest turning the [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) to see the database call activity. Also, since you are returning `IQueryable`, you don't know when exactly it is executed (materialized) and how long it takes (the rest w/o lazy loading should be serialization), so you may try calling `ToList` before returning from the method.

Comment: Instrument the code ,time in and elapsed time on db call.  If not db instrument client side repeat until lag is found.

Comment: How large is the HTML payload (uncompressed) being sent over the wire?

Comment: @IvanStoev I originally had .ToList to provide immediate execution, but removed it in hopes that the IQueryable would instead be slightly faster.  Local DB and Integrated Dev timings are similar for the DB calls (subsecond, usually around 150ms at peak).

Comment: @mjwills 7.6mb, which seems to be a significant problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET or a microservice architecture...

If you have 28,000 records in a database table and request all records over HTTP it is going to be slow.

Part of the reason the request is fast localhost is that all 28,000 records are being sent localhost, not "over the wire" as is the case in production. In production, all 28,000 records have to travel over the internet. Another reason the request may be fast localhost is that your database is running localhost as well, so there again, the data does not have to travel "over the wire". In production, even if the database is internal, the data might still have some distance to travel from the database to the API, also "over the wire" and that is not happening if your database is running localhost as well.

The solution is to implement paging in your API and on the frontend:
[image]

You mentioned the requirement: "but the business preference is to have everything and let a front-end table sort and filter it."

Sorting and filtering is also done in conjunction with paging:
[image]

You might not have realized it at first, but this is one of the most common problems with web applications, and it is always solved with paging or vertical scroll lazy loading web pages and web controls. Downloading all the data so the frontend can do the paging, sorting and filtering is the not the correct way to go about the problem.

Comment: While all this makes sense, I'm worried about latency.  Our users are very used to a distributed application that does not involve any of the internet latency (which is why this is such a huge issue in the first place).  In other parts of our application, we are reliant on calls to an external web service that makes paging problematic. I will definitely look into this and attempt to get a workable solution from it, thank you.